# javascript stylesheet changer not working

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet, alternate

Ok a friend gave me this code, and it doesn't work. I have been looking for a java stylesheet changer, and this is the only one I can find. When I click on the link (to change the style) nothing happens. Help? And I do have trouble understanding javascript so it is difficult for me.

js code:

```
function setActiveStyleSheet(title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
}

function getActiveStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title") && !a.disabled) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function getPreferredStyleSheet() {
  var i, a;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1
       && a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("alt") == -1
       && a.getAttribute("title")
       ) return a.getAttribute("title");
  }
  return null;
}

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
  if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
  }
  else expires = "";
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
  }
  return null;
}

window.onload = function(e) {
  var cookie = readCookie("style");
  var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
  setActiveStyleSheet(title);
}

window.onunload = function(e) {
  var title = getActiveStyleSheet();
  createCookie("style", title, 365);
}

var cookie = readCookie("style");
var title = cookie ? cookie : getPreferredStyleSheet();
setActiveStyleSheet(title);

    }
);
```

Header Stylesheet Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/zerohour.css" title="default" />

<link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/rainbow.css" title="rainbow" />
```

Link Activator Code:

```
<a href="#" 

onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); 

return false;">change style to default</a>



<a href="#" 

onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('rainbow'); 

return false;">change style to rainbow</a>
```

Comment: Try opening the console (Ctrl+Shift+J in FF, F12 in IE, dunno in Chrome) and look if / what error message you get; add what you can find there to the question.

Comment: @Armatus Ctrl+Shift+I in chrome

Comment: @Kirean: Ctrl+Shift+J works as well in Chrome and Chromium

Comment: @xbonez apparently F12 works too.  So, they just chose to make every browser's command theirs :)  Love google.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a useless description. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Do you get any error messages? Also better to use a button rather than a link when you want a button, not a link.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a re-write of what I think you are trying to do:

```
var activeStylesheet = (function() {

  // Store title of default linked stylesheet
  var defaultTitle;

  return {

    // Set the active stylesheet to the link styesheet element with title
    // Set all others to disabled
    setActive: function(title) {
      var link, links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

      for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        link = links[i];

        if (link.rel.indexOf("style") != -1 && link.title) { 
          link.disabled = true; 

          if (link.title == title) {
            link.disabled = false; 
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Return the title of the currently active linked stylesheet,
    // or undefined if none found
    getActive: function() {
      var link, links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

      for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        link = links[i];

        if (link.rel.indexOf("style") != -1 &&
            link.title &&
           !link.disabled) {
          return link.title;
        }
      }
    },

    // Return the title of the link stylesheet element where 
    // rel property contains 'alt'
    getPreferred: function() {
      var link, links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

      for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        link = links[i];

        if (link.rel.indexOf("style") != -1 && 
            link.rel.indexOf('alt') == -1 &&
            link.title) { 
          defaultTitle = title;
          return link.title; 
        }
      }
    }
  };
}());
```

Some buttons to do stuff:

```
<button onclick="
 alert(activeStylesheet.getActive());
">Show title of active stylesheet</button>
<button onclick="
 activeStylesheet.setActive('rainbow');
">Set active stylesheet to "rainbow"</button>
<button onclick="
 activeStylesheet.setActive('default');
">Set active stylesheet to "default"</button>
```

Note that using the title will be case sensitive, so be careful.

You can store the title of the default linked stylesheet in the *defaultTitle* variable, but I don't know what you want to do with it. You have a *setPreferred* that first checks that *defaultTitle* is set and if not, calls *getPreferred*, calls *setActive* with *defaultTitle*.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question isn't tagged `Jquery` but unless you have a strong reason to stick with vanilla Javascript, I would recommend Jquery.

You can switch styles in just two lines of code:

```
$('#foobar').click(function(){
        $('link').attr('href','newstyle.css');
        return false;
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zv677/8/)**

Comment: Hmm ill try it out. How do you make it so it can change my alternative stylesheet instead of my main, so it doesn't mess the code up.

Comment: See the live demo. The first stylesheet will be at `.eq(0)`, the second at `.eq(1)` and so on. You can manipulate whichever stylesheet you want to.

Comment: @xbonez—that doesn't do what the OP does, which is to get/set the active stylesheet.

Comment: It does change the stylesheet being referenced in the `link` tag, but now that you mention it, I think you're right. The changes might not ripple through the page.

Comment: yeah it messes up the whole style, I want the script to change only one part of the style, not the whole thing o.O Should of explained a bit more